# Changing iOS Identifier Name Creates Core Data Error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I've been working with Core Data and everything's been going pretty well. Except today when I altered the identifier of my project, suddenly i get the following error.

```
reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
```

I've tried renaming my files to the new identifier but I keep getting the same error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Some things to check: name of the Xcode data model file (.xcdatamodeld); the model ID you're initializing Core Data with (the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing Product->Clean (Xcode 4)  or Project->Clean All (pre Xcode 4).

Comment: And if you get really desperate, navigate to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete anything that has your project name at the start of its name. I've had issues with Xcode 4 in the past where even a clean fails to cause the .momd to be rebuilt, so that the schema I have on screen isn't correctly updated in the app.

Comment: Worked when I deleted everything in DerivedData. Thanks!